# When to use `short` over `int`?

Tags: c++, int, short

There are many questions that asks for difference between the `short` and `int` integer types in C++, but practically, when do you choose `short` over `int`?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

(See [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24372138/2317532) for more detailed explanation)

**Notes:**

- Generally, `int` is set to the 'natural size' - the integer form that the hardware handles most efficiently
- When using `short` in an array or in arithmetic operations, the `short` integer is converted into `int`, and so this can introduce a hit on the speed in processing `short` integers
- Using `short` can conserve memory if it is narrower than `int`, which can be important when using a large array
- Your program will use more memory in a 32-bit `int` system compared to a  16-bit `int` system

**Conclusion:**

- Use `int` unless you conserving memory is critical, or your program uses a lot of memory (e.g. many arrays). In that case, use `short`.

Comment: Note: There is *no guarantee* that a `short` actually uses less memory than an `int`, it is implementation defined.

Comment: Zero/Sign extending is not **that** expensive. I would not mind the performance hit too much. Once you store a lot of numbers, choose the type with the tightest fit to save memory and thus also increase cache locality. The reduced number of cache misses will usually be more important than the cost of extending from `short` to `int`.

Comment: If memory use is critical, then I break out the counting arguments and search for a reasonable bound on the values, and then I use the smallest integer type that encompasses that. Using `short` from some vague notion of it being smaller is both risky (it may be *too* small) and unreliable (it may be not be as small as you can go). When you care enough about memory use to deviate from `int`, I'd just use `[u]intX_t` for some appropriate `X`.

Comment: @delnan Re "reasonable bound": beware of the [keyhole problem](se.ethz.ch/~meyer/publications/OTHERS/scott_meyers/keyhole.pdf) from introducing gratuitous restrictions.

Comment: @TemplateRex Yes, a very real problem, but even worse when you arbitrarily pick a `short` (or `long` or `char` or whatever), mostly because you didn't even consciously set a restriction that's somewhat grounded in reality (or the back-of-the-envelope version of reality), you just "saved" an unknown amount of memory by introducing a platform-dependent, arbitrary restriction based on a gut feeling.

Comment: Excellent explanation!

Answer (score 31):

You choose `short` over `int` when:

Either

- You want to decrease the memory footprint of the values you're storing (for instance, if you're targeting a low-memory platform),
- You want to increase performance by increasing either the number of values that can be packed into a single memory page (reducing page faults when accessing your values) and/or in the memory caches (reducing cache misses when accessing values), and profiling has revealed that there are performance gains to be had here,
- Or you are sending data over a network or storing it to disk, and want to decrease your footprint (to take up less disk space or network bandwidth). Although for these cases, you should prefer types which specify exactly the size in bits rather than `int` or `short`, which can vary based on platform (as you want a platform with a 32-bit `short` to be able to read a file written on a platform with a 16-bit `short`). Good candidates are the types defined in [stdint.h](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).

And:

- You have a numeric value which does not need to take on any values that can't be stored in a `short` on your target platform (for a 16-bit `short`, this is `-32768`-`32767`, or `0`-`65535` for a 16-bit `unsigned short`).
- Your target platform (or one of you r target platforms) uses less memory for a `short` than for an `int`. The standard only guarantees that `short` is *not larger* than `int`, so implementations are allowed to have the same size for a `short` and for an `int`.

**Note:**

`char`s can also be used as arithmetic types. An answer to *"When should I use `char` instead of `short` or `int`?"* would read very similarly to this one, but with different numbers (`-128`-`127` for an 8-bit `char`, `0`-`255` for an 8-bit `unsigned char`)

In reality, you likely don't actually want to use the `short` type specifically. If you want an integer of specific size, there are types [defined in `<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) that should be preferred, as, for example, an `int16_t` will be 16 bits on every system, whereas you cannot guarantee the size of a `short` will be the same across all targets your code will be compiled for.

Comment: Keeping in mind all considerations listed above, you might also want to consider it to decrease your disk footprint if writing a lot of data to disk.

Comment: @user1074069 Good idea. I've added that (as well as mentioning sending data over the network) and mentioned that you should use fixed width integer types rather than types whose width can vary by platform.

Comment: There is no guarantee that access a memory page as short (16-bit) is faster than int (32-bit).  For example, if you want a 16-bit quantity from memory and the processor word size is 32, the processor may have to shift the bits left or right to place them in the correct position.

Comment: Also, accessing 2 16-bit quantities from memory may be faster using a 32-bit fetch.  Depends on the Memory Management Unit.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I was trying to get across that accessing 2048 16-bit values is likely faster than accessing 2048 32-bit values, as the former fits in 1 memory page (assuming 4 KB pages), while the latter takes 2 memory pages. Is there another way to word my answer to make that more clear? Or are you saying that my assumption there is invalid?

Comment: @EricFinn: In a 32-bit system, accessing 2048 16-bit values is faster accessed as 1024 32-bit values.  Many compilers will often emit code to access even quantities of 16-bit values using 32-bit fetches (2 values with 1 fetch is very efficient).

Comment: @EricFinn: Also remember that a 32-bit data type also satisfies the range conditions for a `short`.  With some compilers and platforms, `short` is the same as `int`, which means when you want 16-bits, you're getting 32.  See `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` data types in `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 13):

In general, you don't prefer `short` over `int`.

**The int type is the processor's native word size**
Usually, an `int` is the processor's word size.

For example, with a 32-bit word size processor, an `int` would be 32 bits.  The processor is most efficient using 32-bits.  Assuming that `short` is 16-bit, the processor still fetches 32-bits from memory.  So no efficiency here; actually it's longer because the processor may have to shift the bits to be placed in the correct position in a 32-bit word.

**Choosing a smaller data type** 
There are standardized data types that are bit specific in length, such as `uint16_t`.  These are preferred to the ambiguous types of `char, short,` and `int`.  These width specific data types are usually used for accessing hardware, or compressing space (such as message protocols).

**Choosing a smaller range**
The `short` data type is based on **range** not bit width.  On a 32-bit system, both `short` and `int` may have the same 32-bit length.

Once reason for using `short` is because the value will never go past a given range.  This is usually a fallacy because programs will change and the data type could overflow.

**Summary**
Presently, I do not use `short` anymore.  I use `uint16_t` when I access 16-bit hardware devices.  I use `unsigned int` for quantities, including loop indices.  I use `uint8_t`, `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` when size matters for data storage.  The `short` data type is ambiguous for data storage, since it is a minimum.  With the advent of `stdint` header files, there is no longer any need for `short`.

Comment: How about a word in amd64? On my platform it's 32-bit, which is neither the 16-bit x86 assembly 'word' nor the actual native word size of a 64-bit processor.

Comment: The bit size of an integer is implementation or compiler dependent after the range (16-bit) is reached.  Some compilers may standardize on 32-bit integers even though the processor supports larger sizes.  Tell the compiler the exact target information and it will perform better code optimization for your target platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any specific constraints imposed by your architecture, I would say you can always use `int`. The type `short` is meant for specific systems where memory is a precious resource.